# PHP CURL not working on 8080

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to make a curl request as shown below. The page takes a long time to load before timing out / displaying an empty page.

```html
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8080);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http1.uk.*******.com/ASM_Relay?Username=****&Password=****&Channel=UK%2EO2&MSISDN=447595344329&Content=HelloWorld');
$content = curl_exec($ch);
echo $content;
?>
```

However if place the url directly in to my browser it returns the expected response.

> http1.uk.*******.com:8080/ASM_Relay?Username=******&Password=*****&Channel=UK%2EO2&MSISDN=44759533229&Content=HelloWorld

I have spent ages trying to figure out why but I am at a total loss.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: ??? `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8088);` `8088 !== 8080`

Comment: Hi sorry that was a typo when I put the question in, it still does not work when that is corrected.

Comment: Please copy/paste your _actual code_. Don't rewrite it for SO since it's then _impossible_ for us to help you find potential bugs and typos...

Comment: apologies, note taken

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ___Hear hear, well said___. Nothing more annoying that debugging pseudo code that is nothing like what is actually causing the probelms

Comment: So how close to the REAL code is what you have shown us now?

Comment: it's exact - minus the credentials

Comment: have your tried using curl_error, or curl_getinfo on that handle to see what might be happening in the background?

Comment: Hello, Im suspecting that there is something like a firewall causing an issue here, I have tried running the code on a different server and it works as expected. I have been in contact with my hosting provider but they assure me that they are not blocking these ports. I'm using a shared host, could this be a plausible explanation?

Comment: Are the cURL script and the browser you tested with on the same computer at the same IP address? Are there IP restrictions on the remote server? Does the script require a User Agent to be passed?

Comment: The error from the 1st server is a time out: error:Failed to connect to http1.uk.***.com port 8080: Connection timed out. The script is on a different ip from the machine where I am using the browser.

Comment: try to `ping` the remote server from the terminal to make sure port `8080` is really not blocked

Comment: Hi, I spoke to someone else at the host support, turns out they were blocking 8080. Thank you very much for your help guys

Comment: @MattBlack, Can you post this as possible answer so that it can be helpful for future users?

Comment: @MattBlack, I am sorry. I thought you would raise a ticket to your hosting provider to unblock the port & then you would post the answer once your issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to someone else at the host support, turns out they were blocking 8080. Thank you very much for your help guys.